# different kinds of array warning in magento

Tags: php, magento, caching, warnings, array-merge

I'm experiencing some warnings in system log of my magento website, some of them i solved but some of them i couldn't find also not on here.

the system log says:
`2012-08-10T13:09:18+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array  in /var/www/sites/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 395`

in phpfile this is the part line 395 is on top

```
$options = array_merge($options, $cacheInitOptions);
$this->_cache = Mage::getModel('core/cache', $options);
$this->_isCacheLocked = false;
return $this;

2012-08-10T13:09:18+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Cache::__construct() must be an array, null given, called in /var/www/sites/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1350 and defined  in /var/www/sites/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 105

Config php.
    $className = $this->getModelClassName($modelClass);
        if (class_exists($className)) {
            Varien_Profiler::start('CORE::create_object_of::'.$className);
       1350 $obj = new $className($constructArguments);
            Varien_Profiler::stop('CORE::create_object_of::'.$className);
            return $obj;

Cache.php line 105=   public function __construct(array $options = array()

2012-08-10T13:09:18+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Cache::_getBackendOptions() must be an array, null given, called in /var/www/sites/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 119 and defined  in /var/www/sites/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 141

cache.php 
line 119  $backend    = $this->_getBackendOptions($options);
line 141  protected function _getBackendOptions(array $cacheOptions)


2012-08-10T13:09:18+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Cache::_getFrontendOptions() must be an array, null given, called in /var/www/sites/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 120 and defined  in /var/www/sites/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 288

cache.php
line 120  $frontend   = $this->_getFrontendOptions($options);
line 288   protected function _getFrontendOptions(array $cacheOptions)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your local.xml file and inspect the cache tag. In my case, while wanting to desactivate the cache, I had commented out everything inside this tag (apc, memcahced, etc) but I had left the tag itself outside of the comment which gave me errors similar as described above.

So try this :

```
<!--
<cache>
<backend>Apc</backend>
....
</cache>
-->
```

but not this :

```
<cache>
<!-- 
    <backend>Apc</backend>
     .... 
-->
</cache>
```

Of course, after that you no more use any cache but at least you may know where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to file permissions. Make sure that the web server has read/write permissions to the cache folder. The cache folder by default is under:

```
<webroot>/var/cache/
```

Notice the cache files are set to read/write only by the file owner, hence the restriction.